# how to get specific column in 2D array using java

Tags: java, arrays, copy

when searched value exist in array, I choose the column and save them.
for example

```
1 2 3 4 5 6
A B C D E F
G H I J K L
```

I want to make a column including `x==1||x==4`
below column will be result of what i want

```
1 4
A D
G J
```

below code is my 2D array code. I make 1D array from csv file and 2D array. when searched value exist, I choose the column and save them.

```
    String str = readCSV(new File("D:/sample_folder/sample1.csv"));
    String[] strArr = parse(str); // It comes out in a row in an String array.
    int varNumber = 45;
    int rowNumber = strArr.length/varNumber;

    String[][] Array2D = new String[varNumber][rowNumber];

    for(int j=0;j<varNumber;j++)
    {
        for(int i=0; i<rowNumber;i++)   
            {
                String k = strArr[i*varNumber+j];
                        Array2D[j][i]= k;
        }
    }                       //make 2D array
```

Comment: Have you tried to approach the problem on your own? If so paste your code here :) If not try yourself and ask a more specific question when getting errors and research does not help.

Comment: What is the format of your csv ? It would be interesting to rotate your array. That way, you will be able to get the column by copying the Array2d[i] in one line. Please give an example to run this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can through rows of 2D array and pick the column you want.

```
for(int j=0;j<rowNumber;j++)
{
    // index starts from 0
    yourArray[j][0] = array2D[j][0];
    yourArray[j][1] = array2D[j][3];
}
```

Or more dynamically you could write:

```
int[] columnsYouWant = {0, 3};
for(int j=0;j<rowNumber;j++)
{
    for(int c=0;c<columnsYouWant.length;c++)
    {
       yourArray[j][c] = array2D[j][columnsYouWant[c]];
    }
}
```

If you want to use if (x == 1 || x == 4) :

```
for(int j=0;j<rowNumber;j++)
{
    column = 0;
    for(int c=0;c<columnNumber;c++)
    {
       x = c + 1;
       if (x == 1 || x == 4)
       yourArray[j][column++] = array2D[j][c];
    }
}
```

I might get it wrong. It also seems you may want to have columns starting with 1 or 4. In that case, if your first row has numbers and rest are alphabetical. You should find the column starting with either 1 or 4.

```
for(int j=0;j<colNumber;j++)
{
   x = array2d[0][j];
   if ( x == 1 || x == 4 ) {
       // add you j to an array
   }
}
```

In the case you will know which columns you want, and you can use the second piece of code in my answer to create 2D array with columns you want.

Comment: I want to use `if(x==1||x==4)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this simulation, I populate this in your 2DArray:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6
A B C D E F
G H I J K L
```

after that, I made a code to print only the columns `1` and `4`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[][] twoDArray = populateArray();
    int x = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < twoDArray.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < twoDArray[0].length; j++) {
            x = j + 1;
            if(x == 1 || x == 4) {
                System.out.print(twoDArray[i][j]);
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

}

public static String[][] populateArray() {
    String[][] twoDArray = new String[3][6];
    for (int i = 0; i < twoDArray[0].length; i++) {
        twoDArray[0][i] = (i + 1) + "";
    }
    char alphaChar = 'A';
    for (int i = 1; i < twoDArray.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < twoDArray[0].length; j++) {
            twoDArray[i][j] = String.valueOf(alphaChar);
            alphaChar++;
        }
    }
    return twoDArray;
}
```

the output of the code is:

```
14
AD
GJ
```

if you comment the `if(x == 1 || x == 4) {` that I used, it will print like this:

```
123456
ABCDEF
GHIJKL
```